# Bootstrap multiselect is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a web application that is attempting to use a bootstrap package from Nuget. I have imported jquery and bootstrap files into the application but on the console for chrome I am getting an error. I am using an ASP.net project to accomplish this.

These are my imports in my htmlcs file:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is my script (at the bottom of the html block):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#chkveg').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the error I'm getting:
[image]

Any ideas? Thank you.

EDIT: Adding the html where I have the dropdown:

```
<select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="test1">Test Option 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test Option 2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you put some html code where you have mention drop down.

Comment: Ok, I added the html code I have for the drop down.

Comment: `multiselect()` isn't a standard part of Bootstrap. It's a third party library which you need to include separately: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 0):

Include the plugin's CSS and JS:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
```