# Bootstrap multiselect is not a function - not checking the multiselect script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420589/bootstrap-multiselect-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment97560996_55420589) question a couple days ago about getting the bootstrap multiselect feature working. I downloaded the multiselect script but I'm still getting the `multiselect is not a function` however, accoring to the browser console, it's not reading the multiselect script.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103898/bootstrap-multiselect-typeerror-multiselect-is-not-a-function), I tried rearranging the scripts loading order, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Here is my html and script code:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
</head>

<select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#chkveg').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the browser console (everything is loaded):
[image]

Any thoughts on the problem? Thank you.

Comment: What version of bootstrap and bootstrap multiselect are you using?

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: And the version of bootstrap?

Comment: According to NuGet, 3.4.1, however I can update it to 4.3.1

Comment: Everything you provided seems like it should be fine. I do see you're still loading jquery 1.12.1, you could go ahead and dequeue that. Perhaps that might be whats causing an issue? If not, I see you're using Modernizr and maybe some sort of optimizations you're running could be causing this problem

Comment: Ok, I'll try to dequeue the older version of jquery. I'm pretty new to this kind of development, I think Modernizr came default with the MVC application. Do you mind explaining what that is?

Comment: Modernizr is a browser compatibility detection framework that lets you leverage new features that aren't widely supported yet. For example, you can use modernizr to detect if the browser loading the page supports webp image format. You can then load webp images for faster pagespeed load. You can see the full list of modernizr features here.

https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses

Comment: @FarzadA I removed all the 1.12.1 scripts, same problem though

Comment: Did you try updating bootstrap to 4.3.1? (dont forget to include popper js)

Comment: The update didn't work either, what do you mean my propper js? My imports still look the same as what I put in the question

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ You need to also include popper if you're using newer versions of bootstrap. If this doesn't do it I'm not sure what it could be, you'd need to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

    <select multiple="multiple" id="chkveg">
       <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
       <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
       <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
    </select>

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#chkveg').multiselect({
              includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Tried the above code in jsfiddle working for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to avoid using external sources, I would like to get this working having the scripts on my internal setup